# JavaScript show and hide tricks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have show or hide on a div. Inside the div is just a simple form. Currently when the page loads i have it set to hide until the checkbox is unchecked.

```
setSameAsBilling: function(flag) {
    $('billing:use_for_shipping').checked = flag;
    if (flag) {
        $('co-shipping-form-fields').hide();
        this.syncWithBilling();
    }
    if (!flag) {
        $('co-shipping-form-fields').show();
    }
},
```

I want it to always show the form. I tried just setting the first conditional statement to `.show()` as well.

Additionally, I've tried to remove some of the styling and or changing the styling in the CSS. Currently it looks like this:

```
#co-shipping-form-fields{margin-top:20px}.checkoutStep--billingshipping .guest-show{display:none}.checkoutStep--billingshipping .guest-checkout .guest-hide{display:none}.
```

I tried to just change it to `display:block` for everything that said `display:none`. Still to no avail.

What is the correct way to accomplish this task? Should i set an `!important` or do i need to adjust the js? There is also some ajax involved which i presume may be the overlying problem here.

[image]

Comment: Children of hidden elements are always hidden.  You can't show the children of a hidden parent.

Comment: Okay, noted*... but there has to be some work around, no?

Comment: No.  That's how encapsulation works.  You don't want it to be hidden.  Make it not a child of that element.

Comment: You need to set a special class on each element that will conditionally show or hired based on your logic

Comment: You can also set a change event that will perform a toggle class for hidden

Comment: How would i go about that? @JudsonTerrell

Comment: I cannot provide code at this moment but I will later if you don't have an answer

Answer (score 1):

There is some kind of a "workaround", when your element needs to be a child of that hidden parent. Using `visibility: hidden` on your parent element and `visibility: visible` on your child element that you want to be shown.

Quickly made a simple snippet for you. Ignore the javascript, it's just for the button:

```js
hideshow = function() {
  if ($("#parent").css("visibility") === "hidden") {
    $("#parent").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("button")[0].innerHTML = "hide parent";
  } else {
    $("#parent").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $("button")[0].innerHTML = "show parent";
  }
}
```

```css
#parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#firstchild {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  visibility: visible
}

#secondchild {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

code {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

button {
  margin: 0 10;
  display: block;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="hideshow()">show parent</button>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="firstchild">
    <code>visible4ever!</code>
  </div>
  <div id="secondchild">
    <code>take me with you, parent!</code>
  </div>
</div>
```

But there's a big difference between `display: none` and `visibility: hidden`. Setting `display` to `none` will **completely** hide an element, whereas `visibility: hidden` does also "hide" it, but won't prevent the element of still occupying it's space. Since I don't know how your form elements and the elements around it look like and how their layout is, I don't know if this difference has any consequences to your site and how you want it to be. Try it out!

---

However, as [Taplar already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806382/javascript-show-and-hide-tricks#comment78570675_45806382), moving the element so it isn't a descendant of the parent you want to hide, is probably the "best" way. `position: absolute` and the `top` and `left` properties will help you out with this.

---

Another way is of course to leave the parent alone and just hide every of it's children except the one you want to show with `display: none`. This can be easy for one or two children you want to hide, but starts to be frustrating the more children your parent has. Also remember, with this method the parent itself isn't hidden. If it has any `background-color` or `border`, they will be shown, even if you would hide every child in it.

---

Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10042276/5707534) to a similar question.

Comment: I'll look into this now. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer for a third option, in case it helps you. :)